# Specifying arguments

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am working some exercises in the craft of functional programming.

Below is an example of how to specify finding the maximum of two numbers:

```
max :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
max x y
 | x >= y = x
 | otherwise = y

max' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
max' x y = 
 if x >= y then x else y

prop_max1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
prop_max1 x y =
 x <= max x y && y <= max' x y
```

I want to use the `prop_max1` function so I write:

```
prop_max1 (max 1 2) (max' 1 2)
```

which returns `True`.

But if I write

```
prop_max1((max 1 2) (max' 1 2))
```

this doesn't work and I get an error along the lines of couldn't match expected type. Why can I not write it this way?

Comment: I can highly recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com (free online text or book)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're familiar with ***Python***, ***Ruby***, ***Java*** or ***C#***, functions are generally invoked as this:

```
func(a, b)
```

While in ***Haskell***, ***F#***, and ***OCaml*** they're invoked like this:

```
func a b
```

This means one term followed by another in Haskell a-la `a b` is a function call a-la `a(b)` in Python.

What this basically boils down to is this:

```
prop_max1 (max 1 2) (max' 1 2) -- is the same as prop_max1(max(1, 2), max'(1, 2))
```

While

```
prop_max1 ((max 1 2) (max' 1 2)) -- is the same as prop_max1(max(1, 2)(max'(1, 2))))
```

Notice how `prop_max1(max(1, 2), max'(1, 2))` and `prop_max1(max(1, 2)(max'(1, 2))))` differ in terms of `()` placement.

---

Side note: A function call that looks like this: `f(a)(b)` is essentially the same as this:

```
g = f(a)
g(b)
```

But written as a single statement, meaning `max(1, 2)(max'(1, 2))` is the same as

```
m1 = max(1, 2) 
m1(max'(1, 2))
```

Same holds for Haskell, where `(max 1 2) (max' 1 2)` is the same as:

```
m1 = max 1 2
m1 (max' 1 2)
```

---

Anyway, it's probably easier to see if we remove the 1 and 2, making it `prop_max1(max, max')` vs `prop_max1(max(max'))`.

In the first case `max` and `max'` are the first and second argument of `prop_max1` respectively, while in the second case `max'` is `max`'s returned function's argument.

That's why `prop_max1 (max 1 2) (max' 1 2)` works, and `prop_max1 ((max 1 2) (max' 1 2))` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
prop_max1((max 1 2) (max' 1 2))
```

Is the same as:

```
prop_max1 ((max 1 2) (max' 1 2))
```

Which you might write, in a language like Python or Java which uses `()` as function invocation, as:

```
prop_max1(max(1, 2)(max'(1, 2)))
```

When you put the parens like that, you're saying that you want to invoke the return value of `max 1 2` with the return value of `max' 1 2`. But `max 1 2` doesn't return a function, so that doesn't typecheck.

Haskell uses the space character to mean function invocation, and parens are only used for grouping expressions. (Er, and for tuples.)